# Docker: Move LibXMLSec settings / dependencies into executable directory

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, package, xmlsec

So. I'm trying to get my Dockerfile to run.

Dockerfile is complicated, and doing things somewhat wrong for Python.  The important part, though, is that it was working before I added XMLSec to the dependencies. (via the onelogin [https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml] package)

On our non-Dockerized systems, we run:

`apt install -y libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libxmlsec1-openssl pkg-config`

and it installs the dependencies. My containerized attempts, however, run into this issue:

```html
  Running setup.py install for xmlsec: started
    Running setup.py install for xmlsec: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-wd6h548m/xmlsec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-ufxw9hor/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'src/xmlsec/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/xmlsec
    copying src/xmlsec/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/xmlsec
    copying src/xmlsec/constants.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/xmlsec
    copying src/xmlsec/template.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/xmlsec
    copying src/xmlsec/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/xmlsec
    copying src/xmlsec/tree.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/xmlsec
    running build_ext
    error: Unable to invoke pkg-config.
```

The solution seems to be to use the XMLSec library as a compiled Wheel. (Per something I read in the XMLSec github) I can't find any documentation on how to add this compiled wheel into an executable location within the container via the Dockerfile.

I've done quite a bit of research on this, and can't find sample code or the exact answer. I it may be obvious, but I'm missing core knowledge.

Comment: Facing the same issue, please let me know if you found a solution.

Comment: "RUN apt update -y && apt install -y libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libxmlsec1-openssl"
ended up working for me.  I was pointing at the wrong repository for building for a while, mong other issues.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I solved this issue with the same solution.